# QueueUtil spawns too many threads for MessageHandlers, async/await problem

Tags: multithreading, azure, async-await, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

**UPDATE:**
The error was in using `Action<QueueMessage> onSuccess` for the actual task and calling it without `await`. We're actually passing an `async` callback as onSuccess and therefore it's not blocking and it is just being fired away without awaiting on it. Changing the type to `Func<QueueMessage, Task>` and calling via `await onSuccess(messageObj)` fixed the behavior.

I'm receiving messages and each message is processed by a long running job involving both IO and CPU intensive routines. My problem is that my registered message handler is being invoked for too many times (basically as many times as there are messages), which makes my process eat 100% of the CPU resource and everything slows down horribly.

I have a wrapper around QueueClient and I think I got in trouble because of it.
I understand that my code is wrong, but I lack enough understanding of how async/await work in .NET to fix it myself.

Here's the wrapper code, it's getting either a json message or a link to Azure Storage, so it handles this logic and passes it to a callback.

```
public static void RegisterReceiver(string queueName,
        Action<QueueMessage> onSuccess, Action<ExceptionReceivedEventArgs> onError)
        _queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
                async (message, cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    var messageObj = new QueueMessage(message);
                    var regex = new Regex(@"\[blob%([^\]]+)\](.+)");
                    if (regex.IsMatch(messageObj.Body))
                    {
                        // Pulling blob data from storage
                        var match = regex.Match(messageObj.Body);
                        messageObj.ContentType = match.Groups[1].Value;
                        messageObj.Body = await BlobUtil.GetAndDeleteBlobAsync(match.Groups[2].Value, settings.QueueBlobStorageName);
                    }
                    onSuccess(messageObj);
                }, 
                new MessageHandlerOptions((exceptionArgs) =>
                {
                    onError(exceptionArgs);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                })
                {
                    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1
                }
            );
```

And here's the calling code with the final callback:

```
QueueUtil.RegisterReceiver(QueueUtil.QUEUE_NAME, 
                async message =>
                {
                    await processService.RunJobs(message);
                }, 
                exceptionArgs =>
                {
                    throw new Exception("Exception occurred while receiving message from " + QueueUtil.QUEUE_NAME, 
                        exceptionArgs.Exception);
                }
            );
```

So somehow with all these async/await things my receiver just keeps spawning threads as soon as messages arrive.

Comment: The handler will be running up-to 5 minutes and if processing is not completed, message will be re-delivered for processing. I don't quite understand where your abstraction is called and how it's hosted in Azure, but Message Handler _is_ expected to be invoked for each message received. While registration should only take place once.

Comment: It's hosted on a VM via kestrel (dotnet My.dll). The problem is that my `processService.RunJobs(message);` gets called multiple times (basically as many times as there are messages) instantly, as opposed to expected behavior of spawning only one message handler per MaxConcurrentCalls option.

Comment: That sounds off. Can you share a link to a repro?

Comment: I'll try to come up with a simplified version of our code.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, after stripping down everything from my project for a repro for you, I've been able to spot an error. We've been incorrectly using a void Action instead of awaitable Func which caused our task to run without being awaited on. I'll update the question, I guess it should be closed, it has nothing to do with the Service Bus after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in using `Action<QueueMessage> onSuccess` for the actual task and calling it without `await`. We're actually passing an `async` callback as onSuccess and therefore it's not blocking and it is just being fired away without awaiting on it. Changing the type to `Func<QueueMessage, Task>` and calling via `await onSuccess(messageObj)` fixed the behavior.

Comment: Yep, that would do it  Awaiting asynchronous methods is important.  Glad you're unblocked.